# Excel VBA - Round function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro to edit the price list my faulty ERP packet generates. I currently get 175,42$, etc and I would like to round them to 175,4$ (depending on the second decimal).

```
  J           K
175,42      175,4 
193,76      193,8

dim i as integer
For i = 16 to 25
   Range("K" & i).Select = "=ROUND(J & i;1)"
Next i
```

So I presume this should run through K16:K25 and use the round function, but it seems to give an error and I'm guessing it's the round function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. VBA has its own function for Round.

Now tested and working for me!

```
dim i as integer
For i = 16 to 25
   Range("K" & i) = Round(Range("J" & i), 1) 
Next i
```

Comment: It is important to note that the VBA `Round()` function behaves differently to the Excel `Round()` Worksheet function. `Round(2.5, 0) in VBA = 2 where as `WorksheetFunction.Round(2.5, 0)` = 3

Comment: Good point. Putting a 1 as the second parameter like I did above I believe rounds it the way Tom desires though. It would round based on the first decimal.

Comment: This works fine for me, I presume someone changed a 0 to 1 to it rounds upto 1 decimal?

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to

```
Range("K" & i).Formula = "=ROUND(J" & i & ";1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 16 To 25
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & i).Formula = "=ROUND(J" & i & ",1)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run it this way, I get application-defined or object-defined error and highlights inside the for loop. (same problem as with chris)

Comment: Updating my post. Try it with a comma

Comment: Yes, I was just confirming it :) What I meant was, I used the other code, but now I could use yours too ;)